# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) Check the render method of `UploadProduct`

Tags: reactjs

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `UploadProduct`.

I don't know what i am missing here it's find to me if anyone got any error please let me know

UploadProduct.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Typography, Button, FormGroup, Input } from "@mui/material";
import FileUpload from "../../utils/FileUpload";
import Axios from "axios";

const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;

const Continents = [
  { key: 1, value: "Africa" },
  { key: 2, value: "Europe" },
  { key: 3, value: "Asia" },
  { key: 4, value: "North America" },
  { key: 5, value: "South America" },
  { key: 6, value: "Australia" },
  { key: 7, value: "Antarctica" },
];

export const UploadProduct = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [TitleValue, setTitleValue] = useState("");
  const [DescriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState("");
  const [PriceValue, setPriceValue] = useState(0);
  const [ContinentValue, setContinentValue] = useState(1);

  const [Images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const onTitleChange = (event) => {
    setTitleValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onDescriptionChange = (event) => {
    setDescriptionValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onPriceChange = (event) => {
    setPriceValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const onContinentsSelectChange = (event) => {
    setContinentValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const updateImages = (newImages) => {
    setImages(newImages);
  };
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (
      !TitleValue ||
      !DescriptionValue ||
      !PriceValue ||
      !ContinentValue ||
      !Images
    ) {
      return alert("fill all the fields first!");
    }

    const variables = {
      title: TitleValue,
      description: DescriptionValue,
      price: PriceValue,
      images: Images,
      continents: ContinentValue,
    };

    Axios.post("/api/product/uploadProduct", variables).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.success) {
        alert("Product Successfully Uploaded");
        history.push("/");
      } else {
        alert("Failed to upload Product");
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: "700px", margin: "2rem auto" }}>
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginBottom: "2rem" }}>
        <Title level={2}> Upload Travel Product</Title>
      </div>

      <FormGroup onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {/* DropZone */}
        <FileUpload refreshFunction={updateImages} />

        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Title</label>
        <Input onChange={onTitleChange} value={TitleValue} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Description</label>
        <TextArea onChange={onDescriptionChange} value={DescriptionValue} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Price($)</label>
        <Input onChange={onPriceChange} value={PriceValue} type="number" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <select onChange={onContinentsSelectChange} value={ContinentValue}>
          {Continents.map((item) => (
            <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>
              {item.value}{" "}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />

        <Button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </FormGroup>
    </div>
  );
};
```

MainRoute.js

```
import {  UploadProduct } from '../Components/UploadProduct/UploadProduct'


<Route exact path="/product/upload">
  <UploadProduct/>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title and TextArea don't exist on Typography and Input

```
const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;
```

Comment: Thank you :) it's rendered now